# What effect do brackets have around propositional statements?

Tags: logic

I want to know the effects of bracket around propositional statements.

For example is number 1 and number two the same? 
1) ¬(p∧q) 
2) ¬p∧¬q

Thanks

Comment: No, they aren't. The second is *true* only when both $p$ and $q$ are *false*, while the first one is *true* also when either $p$ or $q$ are *false*.

Comment: No, "$\neg$" precedes "$\wedge$".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so essentially  ¬(p∧q) is the opposite to p∧q?

Comment: Yes, indeed that is what that expression means. It is the **negation** of what is written inside the brackets

Comment: Yes; $\lnot \varphi$ is **always** the "opposite" of $\varphi$.

Comment: They are not the same; similarly if $a$ and $b$ are numbers, $-(a×b)$ and $-a×-b$ mean different things and usually have different values.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages Check here

Comment: ¬(p∧q) is equivalent to ¬p∨¬q.